# JOIN one tables where two columns are id in other table

Tags: mysql

First of all, any suggestion to improve my question title is more than welcome. Here is my explanation.

I have two tables. One is flights and the other is airports.

```
flights
-------------------------------------------------------------------
id | departure_id | destination_id | departure_date | arrival_date
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |1             | 5              | 2014-05-01     | 2014-05-01
-------------------------------------------------------------------

airports
-----------------------------------
id | country_id | name | timezone |
-----------------------------------
1  | 1          | TPE  | +08:00   |
-----------------------------------
5  | 2          | HND  | +09:00   |
-----------------------------------
```

and I need this result:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
departure_date | departure_tz | arrival_date | arrival_tz |
-----------------------------------------------------------
2014-05-01     | +08:00       | 2014-05-01   | +09:00   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I have this query, but is not giving me the result I want because I do not how to make the relation between destination_id, departure_id with the table aiports, both of them are id in the airports table, any suggestion please. This is the query I have but with no distinction between timezone that is the info I want to show the most.

```
SELECT flights.flight_number,
  flights.departure_date,
  airports.timezone as departure_tz,
  flights.arrival_date,
  airports.timezone as arrival_tz
FROM flights
JOIN airports
```

Comment: Try adding an `on` clause (or `using` if you like).  MySQL allows the very  quirky syntax of a `join` clause with no `on` clause.  This would be an error in any other database.

Comment: Join twice from flights to airports.  Once for Departures, once for destination.

Comment: I used ON too, however the condition seems not distinct between them. I tried with this, but no results.

    SELECT flights.flight_number,
    flights.departure_date,
    airports.timezone as departure_tz,
    flights.arrival_date,
    airports.timezone as arrival_tz
    FROM flights
   JOIN airports
   ON flights.departure_id = airports.id
   AND flights.destination_id = airports.id

Comment: @xQbert is it possible to join twice the same tables? I tried to do it and got an error.

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Kristian,Alex and Mate have provided answers that do just that.  Note you must ALIAS the tables differently.  in your example don't use and... use or  since you want either join... However this would result in two separate rows, which is why I think the below answers will better suit your need.

Comment: @xQbert thanks, I am going to try the examples and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT flights.flight_number,
flights.departure_date,
A1.timezone as departure_tz,
flights.arrival_date,
A2.timezone as arrival_tz
FROM (flights JOIN airports as A1 ON flights.departure_id=A1.id)
JOIN airports as A2 on flights.departure_id=A2.id
```

`ON` where missing from your query and also as you want to join to two separate rows from airports you need to use two instances of that table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT flights.flight_number,
  flights.departure_date,
  dep.timezone as departure_tz,
  flights.arrival_date,
  arvl.timezone as arrival_tz
FROM flights
LEFT JOIN airports dep
ON flights.departure_id = dep.id
LEFT JOIN airports arvl
ON flights.destination_id = arvl.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 2 joins?

```
SELECT 
t1.id AS flight_number 
t1.departure_date,
t2.timezone AS departure_tz 
t1.arrival_date
t3.timezone AS arrival_tz
FROM flights t1
LEFT JOIN airports t2
ON t1.departure_id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN airports t3
ON t1.arrival_id = t3.id
```